# Quick algebra question regarding fields and their elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm not sure if I'm getting this right.
Assume we have a field $F$ and its four elements are $a,b,c,d$ and have $a+b=ab=c$.

First of all, where is my mistake in the following?
\begin{align}
&a+b=ab \\
\\
\Leftrightarrow\quad& \frac{a+b}{ab}=\frac{ab}{ab} \\
\\
\Leftrightarrow\quad& \frac{a}{ab}+\frac{b}{ab}=1 \\
\\
\Leftrightarrow\quad& a+b=1
\end{align}
And secondly, how can I find the inverse element $a^{-1}$ if it exists?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $a=0$; then $ab=0$, so $b=a+b=0$. Similarly if $b=0.

So we can assume $a\ne0$ and $b\ne0$. You can surely say
$$
\frac{a+b}{ab}=1
$$
but this becomes
$$
\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=1
$$
and not $a+b=1$.

From $a+b=ab$, you get
$$
ab-a=b
$$
or
$$
a=\frac{b}{b-1}
$$
provided $b\ne1$. But $b=1$ would imply $a+1=a$ or $1=0$ that's invalid in a field. Thus you get
$$
a^{-1}=\frac{b-1}{b}
$$
because we are in the case $b\ne0$.

Answer (score 1):

1. $a+b=ab$ is not equivalent to $\frac{a+b}{ab}=\frac{ab}{ab}$. The first statement makes sense even if $ab=0$. The second does not.
2. $\frac{a}{ab} + \frac{b}{ab} = 1$ is not equivalent to $a+b=1$ *at all*. You made a mistake here.